# How to make custom Linkify android?

Tags: android, linkify

Is any library for custom Linkify?. When I click link it need to find link text.i already tried this http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-custom-hyperlinked-textview.html
but it not working good in List view...Thanks for advance.